# Using a Salesforce Data Extension as an entry source in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, data, automation

I have a Salesforce Data Extension in Marketing Cloud that is filtering through people with a specific name.

When I add someone with that name to my list they get picked up by that data extension.

How can I use a Salesforce Data Extension as an entry point for a journey in Journey Builder? Ideally I would want them to start on the journey when they enter the Salesforce Data Extension.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the statement in this Salesforce [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_select_data_extension_for_entry.htm&type=5):

> Salesforce data extensions are no longer selectable as entry sources within Journey Builder. To use a Salesforce data extension as an entry source, use an automation to move its data into a supported format for entry.

So you can not use Salesforce data extensions for the entry source.

They also proposed steps for the workaround:

> 1. Create a data extension that you can populate with data from a Salesforce data extension.
> 2. To populate the new data extension with data from a Salesforce data extension, create an automation with a query activity.